# Get row value datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

How can I get the value of row that I already tick(checkbox).

```
Dim f_Cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = Nothing
For Each f_Row As DataGridViewRow In dgvUserAccessList.Rows
    f_Cell = DirectCast(f_Row.Cells("Input"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
```

Comment: `Dim checkedRows = dgvUserAccessList.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Where(Function(row) DirectCast(row.Cells("Input").Value, Boolean)).ToList()`

Comment: @Fabio but I got more than one row.

Comment: You will if "Input" column was checked in more then one row. If you checked only one row then result will be `List<dataGridViewRow>` with only one item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230432/how-can-i-check-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-datagridview-column-in-vb-net

Comment: Got it @Fabio. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Dejan for the link.