# datagridview values remove from another datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two datagridviews. One is dtgridPopulate and is populated with data from the database.

dtgridPopulate columns are (checkbox, code, name)

| checkbox | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| checkbox icon | c1 | customer_one |

Then the second datagridview is dtgridGenerate which has generated values from dtgridPopulate.
I use the code `dtgridPopulate.Rows.Add(code, name)` to add manually the value from dtgridPopulate to dtgridGenerate.

dtgridGenerate columns are (code, name)

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| c1 | customer_one |

When I check the checkbox in the dtgridPopulate it will transfer the values (code, name) to the dtgridGenerate. But the problem is when I uncheck the checkbox in the dtgridPopulate, It should also **REMOVE** the values in the dtgridGenerate.

```
        Private Sub dtgridPopulateSelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles dtgridPopulate.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

        RemoveHandler dtgridPopulate.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf dtgridPopulateSelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

        If TypeOf dtgridPopulate.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
            dtgridPopulate.EndEdit()
            Dim Checked As Boolean = CType(dtgridPopulate.CurrentCell.Value, Boolean)
            If Checked Then
                code = dtgridPopulate.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                name = dtgridPopulate.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
                dtgridGenerate.Rows.Add(code, name)
            Else
               For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In dtgridPopulate.SelectedRows 'This is for uncheck but it doens't work
                    dtgridGenerate.Rows.Remove(row)
                Next
            End If
        End If

        AddHandler dtgridPopulate.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, AddressOf dtgridPopulateSelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    End Sub
```

I refer to this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230432/how-can-i-check-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-datagridview-column-in-vb-net)

Error when I uncheck the checkbox: **row provided does not belong to this datagridview control. parameter name: datagridviewrow**

Comment: What's with all those `AddHandler` / `RemoveHandler`? You usually handle `CellContentClick` or `CellClick` and `CellValueChanged` to updated a CheckBoxColumn immediately -- You're trying to remove a Row that belongs to a different DataGridView,  `dtgridGenerate` won't find that Row (because it doesn't have it). You need to select it based on the value of the `code` Column in the current Row of `dtgridGenerate`, if it's unique, otherwise a combination of values -- You have a typo in `dtgridGenerate.Rows.Remove(row)` (`row` doesn't exist).

Comment: hi @Jimi, the code `addhandler` I refer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230432/how-can-i-check-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-datagridview-column-in-vb-net

Comment: I know. that is why in my current code I remove the code under `dtgridPopulate` uncheck checkbox. but I don't know what should I do next to remove the rows of `dtgridGenerate` when I uncheck the checkbox of `dtgridPopulate`

Comment: Couldn't this all be handled directly via data binding?  Seems a whole more simple to me rather than all this creating/removing rows to me.  Pretty sure you could even work it with both grids bound to the same DataTable and using a filter on the second DVG for the field corresponding to your checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure “why” you have unsubscribed and then re-subscribed to the event. Typically, this is only needed if the code in the event “changes” something in the grid that would cause the event to re-fire and this is not happening in your current code. Nor is ending the grids edit necessary.

Also, your use of the grids `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event has one drawback in relation to what you want to do… it will NOT re-fire if the user checks and unchecks the same cell over and over. In other words, if the user clicks a check box cell and the check box becomes checked and the event fires… then … if the user “unchecks” the same cell before clicking on any other cell, then the event will NOT refire.

Also, it looks like the event is using a different grid from the signature of the event… `dtgridPopulateSelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` … ? … “SelectAll” and the grid in the event is called… `dtgridPopulate` … this is confusing.

Given this, I suggest two things to help. 1) create and use an “Empty” `DataTable` for the second grid. This way we could simply add and remove items from that table. 2) use the grids `CellContnetClick` event for this. It will re-fire if the user clicks on the same cell over and over in addition to firing ONLY when the check box is changed.

So, I propose these small changes. First add a global variable named `generateDT` as a `DataTable` used as a `DataSource` to the second grid. Initially this table would be empty. Second use the grids `CellContentClick` event to make these additions and removal of the rows.

```
Dim generateDT As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
  dt.Columns.Add("checkbox", GetType(Boolean))
  dt.Columns.Add("code", GetType(String))
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
  dt.Rows.Add(False, "c1", "customer 1")
  dt.Rows.Add(False, "c2", "customer 2")
  dt.Rows.Add(False, "c3", "customer 3")
  dtgridPopulate.DataSource = dt
  generateDT = New DataTable()
  generateDT.Columns.Add("code", GetType(String))
  generateDT.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
  dtgridGenerate.DataSource = generateDT
End Sub
```

Then in the cell content click event, if the clicked cell is a check box cell, then… grab the checked state and both the `code` and `name` of the clicked-on row. Then if the check box cell is checked, then simply add the `code` and `name` to the second grids global `DataTable` variable `generateDT`. If the check box is unchecked, then we will loop through each row in the second grid and if we find a match then simply remove that row from the second grids global `DataTable`… something like…

```
Private Sub dtgridPopulate_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dtgridPopulate.CellContentClick
  If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    Dim Checked = CType(dtgridPopulate.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).EditedFormattedValue, Boolean)
    Dim code = dtgridPopulate.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
    Dim Name = dtgridPopulate.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
    If Checked Then
      generateDT.Rows.Add(code, Name)
    Else
      Dim rowToRemove As DataRowView
      For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtgridGenerate.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString() = code Then
          rowToRemove = CType(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
          generateDT.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove.Row)
          Exit For
        End If
     Next
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. it was a great help. you're the best.